# Codes not generating any plots

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, configuration

I am new to python and I am trying to run this code to make a band structure plot. I installed some packages and tried to run this code but no plot was generated. Could you help me check what's going on?

Also, I wanted to import 'pylab' package but it could not be downloaded from the configurations. Sorry this is quite lengthy but im not sure where the problem comes from. I'm trying to run this with pycharm. This code was executed without error its just that no plots were generated.

```
#exit()

#ipython --pylab=qt
#execfile("photon_band_structures_v4_real_units.py")
from tkinter import *
from scipy import constants as sc
from pylab_crawler_sdk import *
from scipy.optimize import brentq
from cmaths import *
from cmat import *
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy import *
import numpy as np

matplotlib.rc('xtick',labelsize=10)
matplotlib.rc('ytick',labelsize=10)

def kz1(om,n1,kpp):
    kz1 =  emath.sqrt(om**2*n1**2/(c**2) - kpp**2)
    return kz1

def kz2(om,n2,kpp):
    kz2 = sqrt(om**2*n2**2/(c**2)-kpp**2)
    return kz2

def kB(om,kpp,a,b,n1,n2):
    term1 = cos(kz1(om,n1,kpp)*a)*cos(kz2(om,n2,kpp)*b)
    pm = kz2(om,n2,kpp)/kz1(om,n1,kpp)
    term2 = -0.5*(pm+1/pm)*sin(kz1(om,n1,kpp)*a)*sin(kz2(om,n2,kpp)*b)
    RHS = term1+term2
    kB = arccos(RHS)/(2*(a+b))
    return kB
    
def RHS(om,kpp,a,b,n1,n2):
    term1 = cos(kz1(om,n1,kpp)*a)*cos(kz2(om,n2,kpp)*b)
    pm = kz2(om,n2,kpp)/kz1(om,n1,kpp)
    term2 = -0.5*(pm+1./pm)*sin(kz1(om,n1,kpp)*a)*sin(kz2(om,n2,kpp)*b)
    RHS = term1+term2
    return RHS
    
def bandedges(RHSs, kpp, a,b, n1, n2):
    indices1 = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(np.array(RHSs) - 1)) != 0).reshape(-1)
    indices2 = np.argwhere(np.diff(np.sign(np.array(RHSs) + 1)) != 0).reshape(-1)
    idx = indices1
    idx = np.append(indices1,indices2)
    idx.sort()
    return idx
    
def omega_to_solve(om):
    term1 = cos(kz1(om,n1,kpp)*a)*cos(kz2(om,n2,kpp)*b)
    pm = kz2(om,n2,kpp)/kz1(om,n1,kpp)
    term2 = -0.5*(pm+1/pm)*sin(kz1(om,n1,kpp)*a)*sin(kz2(om,n2,kpp)*b)
    RHS = term1+term2
    return abs(RHS)-1
    
def meff(kpps,band):
    curve = polyfit(kpps,band,2)[0]
    meff = hbar/(2*curve) #Modified 5/9/17 by RAN: hbar NOT hbar**2
    return meff

def cutoff(kpps,band):
    offset = polyfit(kpps,band,2)[2]
    return offset


n_spacings = 5

selector=1
if selector==0:        
    c=1
    n1 = sqrt(2.33)
    n2 = sqrt(17.88)
    full_period=2
    a=1
    b=full_period-a
    hbar = 1
    oms = linspace(0.001,5,500)
    n_bands = 6
    interval = 0.05
    #First reproduce band edges for even spacing
    kpps = linspace(0.01,2,200)
    a_range = linspace(0.9,1.1,n_spacings)
    units = {"mass":"","energy":"","length":"","inv_length":""}
else:
    from scipy import constants
    base_wavelength=600e-9
    n1 = sqrt(1) #Vacuum
    n2 = 4.0 #GaAs at around 600 nm
    #n2 = 2.5 #LiF at around 600 nm is n=1.4, but this doesn't really solve
    c=constants.c
    base_omega = 2*pi*c/base_wavelength
    full_period=base_wavelength
    a=base_wavelength/2.0
    b=full_period - a
    hbar = constants.hbar
    oms = linspace(0.001,5,500) * base_omega
    n_bands = 6
    #interval = 0.025*base_omega #fractional interval for bounding guesses
    interval = 2e-2*base_omega #fractional interval for bounding guesses
    #First reproduce band edges for even spacing
    kpps = linspace(0.01,0.5,200)* 2*pi/base_wavelength
    a_range = linspace(0.9,1.2,n_spacings) * base_wavelength/2
    units = {"mass":" (kg)","energy":" (s$^{-1}$)","length":" (m)","inv_length":" (m$^{-1}$)"}
    

#Start by calculating the bottom of the bands
kpp=0
RHSs = [RHS(i,kpp,a,b,n1,n2) for i in oms]
indices = bandedges(RHSs, kpp, a,b, n1, n2)
om_cutoff = [oms[s] for s in indices]
####print "Band bottoms are at: ", om_cutoff

bands = [[] for i in range(n_bands)]    
kpp = 0    
RHSs = [RHS(k,kpp,a,b,n1,n2) for k in oms]
indices = bandedges(RHSs, kpp, a,b, n1, n2)
om_cutoff = [oms[s] for s in indices]

#Now extend out to non-zero kpp
for i,om_bottom in enumerate(om_cutoff[0:n_bands]):
        #kB = (i+1)*pi/2
        #lower_bound,upper_bound = om_bottom-interval, om_bottom+interval
        lower_bound,upper_bound = om_bottom-interval, om_bottom+interval
        #print i, lower_bound, upper_bound
        for kpp in kpps:
            om = brentq(omega_to_solve,lower_bound,upper_bound)
            bands[i] = bands[i]+[om]
            lower_bound,upper_bound = om-interval, om+interval

plt.figure(4), plt.clf()
for n in range(n_bands):
    plt.plot(kpps, bands[n])
plt.xlabel("kpp"+units["inv_length"])
plt.ylabel("$\omega$")
 
#Now focus on small kpp, vary a, keeping a+b=2 and find effective masses of band edges
collected_masses = []
collected_cutoffs = []

#kpps = linspace(0.01,0.5,200) #Look only at parabolic region near kpp=0

for a in a_range:
    #b=2-a #this must be fixed!
    b=full_period - a #this must be fixed!
    bands = [[] for i in range(n_bands)]    
    #Calculate starting point    
    kpp = 0
    RHSs = [RHS(k,kpp,a,b,n1,n2) for k in oms]
    indices = bandedges(RHSs, kpp, a,b, n1, n2)
    om_cutoff = [oms[s] for s in indices]
    #Calculate the rest
    for i,om_bottom in enumerate(om_cutoff[0:n_bands]):
        kB = (i+1)*pi/2
        lower_bound,upper_bound = om_bottom-interval, om_bottom+interval
        for kpp in kpps:
            om = brentq(omega_to_solve,lower_bound,upper_bound)
            bands[i] = bands[i]+[om]
            lower_bound,upper_bound = om-interval, om+interval
    #Fit for effective mass
    masses = [meff(kpps,bands[i]) for i in range(n_bands)[1:]]
    collected_masses = collected_masses + [masses]
    cutoffs = [cutoff(kpps,bands[i]) for i in range(n_bands)[1:]]
    collected_cutoffs = collected_cutoffs + [cutoffs]

transpose_mass = [[collected_masses[i][n] for i in range(n_spacings)] for n in range(n_bands-1)]

transpose_cutoffs = [[collected_cutoffs[i][n] for i in range(n_spacings)] for n in range(n_bands-1)]

plt.figure(5),plt.clf()
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
for n in range(n_bands-1):
    plt.plot(a_range, transpose_mass[n])
plt.xlabel("a"+units["length"])
plt.ylabel("meff"+units["mass"])
plt.grid(1)

plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
for n in range(n_bands-1):
    plt.plot(a_range, transpose_cutoffs[n])
plt.xlabel("a"+units["length"])
plt.ylabel("cutoff" + units["energy"])
plt.grid(1)

plt.figure(6), plt.clf()
for n in range(n_bands-1):
    plt.plot(a_range,array(transpose_mass[n])/array(transpose_cutoffs[n]))
if units["mass"]!="":
    ratio_units = " (m s)"
else:
    ratio_units = ""
plt.ylabel("meff / cutoff"+ratio_units)
plt.xlabel("a"+units["length"])
```

Comment: if you're running from pycharm, you probably need to add `plt.show()` at the end of the script.

Comment: I tried to add this at the end but still no plot was generated..